# Relation between hypergeometric functions $_2F_1$ of $z$ and $\frac{1}{1+z}$.

Tags: calculus, special-functions, hypergeometric-function

What are the relation between hypergeometric functions $_2F_1$ of $z$ and $\frac{1}{1+z}$.

Specifically, I need a transformation that transforms:

$_2F_1\left(a,b;c; -\sinh^2(x)\right)$
to $_2F_1\left(a',b';c'; \cosh^{-2}(x)\right)$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think we'll make two transformation 1) $z\rightarrow \frac{1}{z}$ after 2) $\frac{1}{z} \rightarrow \frac{z}{z-1}$ ??

Comment: Please, see the transformation $z\to \frac{1}{1-z}$ here http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.8

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, if we use [DLMF 15.8.3](http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.8.E3) and $a\neq b$ then
$$
F\left({a,b\atop c};-\sinh^2x\right)=\frac{(b)_{-a}}{(c)_{-a}}\cosh^{-2a}x\ F\left({a,c-b\atop a-b+1};\cosh^{-2}x\right)
+\frac{(a)_{-b}}{(c)_{-b}}\cosh^{-2b}x\ F\left({b,c-a\atop b-a+1};\cosh^{-2}x\right).
$$
If $a=b$ we end up with an indeterminate form that will require L'Hôpital.